# Stepper next steps are not start from top - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

When I finish the first step and click the continue button, It opens the next step properly but, It does not start from the top. It starts from the bottom. The user has to scroll up to read.

This screenshot shows what happened clearly,

- 1st Screenshot - completed step 01 and press continue
- 2nd Screenshot - It shows the bottom of step 02.

[image: Done first step]

[image: SS 2]

My code here:

Stepper: `int currentStep = 0;`

```
Stepper(
            type: StepperType.horizontal,
            steps: getSteps(),
            currentStep: currentStep,
            onStepContinue: () {
              final isLastStep = currentStep == getSteps().length - 1;
              if (isLastStep) {
                print("completed");
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  currentStep += 1;
                });
              }
            },
            onStepCancel: () {
              setState(() {
                currentStep -= 1;
              });
            },
),
```

getSteps:

```
List<Step> getSteps() => [
Step(
 isActive: currentStep >= 0, title: Text("step1"), content: Form1()),
Step(
 isActive: currentStep >= 1, title: Text("step2"), content: Form2()),
];
```

`Form1` and `Form2` just return a lorem text.